# How to serve a PDF file via a HTTP request

Tags: http, pdf

I'm working with some new SCADA software, which uses a browser environment to display everything. One component that the software has is a PDF viewer, however, since we're in a browser environment, it can only load files that are served up over HTTP. According to the [forums](https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/question-pdf-viewer-file-path/20715), this means that the source of the PDF needs to be a URL.

The forum also notes that I can use one of their modules (WebDev) to "stream the PDF bytes over HTTP", and provides directions for how to do so. However, the WebDev module is outside the budget of my project (it's quite a high-powered module, I'd be paying a premium price and then using 1% of its functionality). So I'm wondering if it's possible to serve up a PDF via HTTP some other way.

I'm not an experienced programmer - I'm self taught out of necessity on a small handful of languages, and to a basic level only. As such, I don't fully understand the problem, nor do I know what search terms to use to find the sort of information I need to solve it.

If anyone's able to provide a partial solution, or even just able to help me understand what I'm asking for and where to go looking for some answers, I'd appreciate it!

The PC hosting the PDF files and the SCADA gateway is running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue integrating .pdf report to our SCADA system having web interface and running node.js at backend.

The main point is:

1. Generate your pdf in client end (web interface)
2. Convert it to Base64 format as URi
3. Preview on DOM or send it to server!

[Send excel and pdf to server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271078/how-i-can-send-tabulator-excel-object-to-server-side-node-js)
hope that helps!