# How i can send -tabulator excel- object to server side (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, tabulator

I can export tabulator table to excel with success and store it as file on local computer. However i don't know how to send excel object to server.

How i can convert tabulator excel to base64 before save to local computer and send it to server side?

I already do the same thing with jsPdf and send pdf using:
doc.output('datauristring').

The success scenario should be:
1. Produce excel object (on client side)
2. Convert it to base64 Uri (on client side)
3. Send it to server side (node.js)
4. Convert it again to file (use of fs. to write on local path)

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

Let me give you the working scenario of sending pdf to server. The same thing must be done with xlsx. I've tried to store tabulator object to variable before save to local client computer, but with no success.

```
    table.download("xlsx", "test.xlsx", {sheetName:"testName"});
```

**WORKING SCENARIO WITH PDF**

1. CREATE PDF ON CLIENT END

```
function canvasRun(){            
        // SYSTEM DATE TO ADD AS NAME
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = dd+ '-' + mm + '-' +yyyy;
                                             html2canvas(document.getElementById("grid")).then(function(canvas) {

        //var doc = new jsPDF("l","mm","a4",true); //landscape, millimetre, A4, pdfCompression
        var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
        var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        doc.text("Test1 : "+ today, 110, 15);  // TEXT AT THE CENTER OF REPORT
        doc.text('Test2 : '+ grandTotal +' mm', 200, 15);  // TEXT AT THE CENTER OF REPORT
        doc.addImage(logo, 'PNG', 10, 1, 38, 20,'FAST');// MARGINS LEFT,TOP,WIDTH,HEIGHT

        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, 20,width-20, height-20,'','FAST');
        doc.save('testReport-'+today+'.pdf'); // DOWNLOAD TO LOCAL COMPUTER

        });//HTMLCanvas end
        flagGeneratedPdf=1;
        }
```

2. SEND PDF TO SERVER SIDE

```
function sendToServer(){

// CONVERT PDF FILE TO BASE64 STREAM URI
var convPDF= doc.output('datauristring'); 

// LOAD URI PDF TO OBJECT
var obj = new Object;
obj.attachment=convPDF;

.....
.....

//method to send data to server        
}
```

3. SERVER ACCEPTS OBJECT AND PROCESS IT

```
    function dataFromClient(attachment){

    // CONVERT INCOMING URi TO base64 FILE AND REMOVE MIME TYPE FROM HEADER
    let base64String = attachment;
    let base64pdf = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();

    // GENERATE PDF LOCAL SERVER FILE, IF EXIST REPLACE...
    fs.writeFile("test.pdf", base64pdf,{encoding:'base64'}, (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Successfully Written to File.");});
    }
```

**[SOLVED]**

I figured out the solution using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281449/4636906)

1. Intercept Tabulator's blob object

```
downloadReady:function(fileContents, blob){

getBase64(blob);

return blob;
},
```

2. Convert blob to base64 dataUri with this method

```
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
    // console.log(reader.result);
     var xlsxUriString =reader.result;
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

3. Send `xlsxUriString` to server side (node.js)
4. Convert base64 to file and save it to local folder

```
 let base64StringXlsx = attachment2;
 let base64Xlsx = base64StringXlsx.split(';base64,').pop();

 fs.writeFile("D:/testFolder/test.xlsx", base64Xlsx,{encoding:'base64'}, (err) => {
             if (err) console.log(err);
             console.log("Successfully Written to File xlsx.");
});
```

Comment: Please post the code so that we can see what you have tried.

Comment: Finally i figured out the solution @AritraChakraborty , thanks!