# How i can use Tabulator's downloadReady: callback function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, tabulator

How i can properly use of `downloadReady:function(fileContents, blob){}` in order to upload an xlsx file to server side?

what are the preparations should be made at client side before send file? ex. conversion to Uri maybe? and what steps needed to decode file to server side? from Uri to xlsx file.

**fileContents** returns ArrayBuffer() {} as result which consist of [[Int8Array]] and [[Uint8Array]].
and **blob** returns data type.

The goal is to take the file from client and upload it to server (node.js) then save it locally with fs.write().

if you have any snippet code will be helpful just to realize the steps!

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
What i've used without success! **CLIENT SIDE**

```
downloadReady:function(fileContents, blob){

var xlsxObject = new Object;
xlsxObject.data = fileContents;
sendObjectToServer(xlsxObject);

return blob;
},
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
fs.writeFile("test.xlsx", xlsxObject,{encoding:'base64'}, (err) => {
             if (err) console.log(err);
             console.log("Successfully Written to File xlsx.");
});
```

the file is written but empty with undefined value

**[SOLVED]**

I finally found a solution, if you are interested check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58271078/4636906)

Comment: Have you tried any of the first few results for ["save ArrayBuffer from client to server"](https://www.google.com/search?q=save+ArrayBuffer+from+client+to+server)

Comment: Yes I've tried some examples (also with blob and buffer array) but surely  i'm missing something with encoding and decoding file.

Comment: Thanks @laggingreflex for your recommendations! i've found a solution